# Redirect from one traefik to another one to, to a docker registry

Tags: traefik, consul, nomad

I have been trying to redirect requests from one traefik to another traefik and finally to access a docker registry.

It works but if I try to pull a bigger image, it fails.

First traefik:

```
[entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"

      [entryPoints.http.http]
        [entryPoints.http.http.redirections]
          [entryPoints.http.http.redirections.entryPoint]
            to = "https"
            scheme = "https"

    [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"
```

Second traefik:

```
job "traefik-docker-test" {
  region      = "global"
  datacenters = ["dc1"]
  type        = "service"

  group "traefik-docker-test" {
    count = 1

    network {
      port "http" {
        to = 5000
      }

      port "external" {
        to = 80
      }
    }

    task "traefik-test" {
      driver = "docker"

      config {
        image       = "traefik:2.11"
        force_pull  = true
        ports       = ["external"]
        volumes     = [
          "local/traefik.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml",
          "local/traefik-test.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik-test.yml",
        ]
        logging {
          type   = "journald"
          config {
            tag = "TEST-TRAEFIK"
          }
        }
      }

      template {
        destination     = "local/traefik.yml"
        left_delimiter  = "{{{"
        right_delimiter = "}}}"
        data            = <<EOF
---
log:
  level: INFO

providers:
  file:
    filename: "/etc/traefik/traefik-test.yml"

entryPoints:
  web:
    address: ":80"

EOF
      }

      template {
        destination     = "local/traefik-test.yml"
        left_delimiter  = "{{{"
        right_delimiter = "}}}"
        data            = <<EOF

---

http:
  routers:
    registry-test:
      rule: "Host(`registry-test.mydomain.ai`)"
      service: "registry-test"
      middlewares:
        - "auth-forward"
      entryPoints:
        - "web"
  {{{ with service "docker-test" }}}
  services:
    registry-test:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "http://{{{ (index . 0).Address }}}:{{{ (index . 0).Port }}}"
  {{{ end }}}
       {{{ with service "auth-service" }}}
  middlewares:
    auth-forward:
      forwardAuth:
        address: "http://{{{ (index . 0).Address }}}:{{{ (index . 0).Port }}}"
        trustForwardHeader: true
        authResponseHeaders:
          - "X-Forwarded-Method"
        {{{ end }}}

EOF
      }

      resources {
        cpu    = 100
        memory = 128
      }

      service {
        name = "test-traefik"
        port = "external"

        tags = [
          "traefik.enable=true",
          "traefik.http.routers.test-traefik.rule=Host(`registry-test.mydomain.ai`)",
          "traefik.http.routers.test-traefik.tls.certResolver=mydomain-le",
          "traefik.http.routers.test-traefik.tls=true",
        ]

        check {
          name     = "alive"
          type     = "tcp"
          port     = "external"
          interval = "10s"
          timeout  = "2s"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see I'm also using consul to resolve between services.

The login to the `middlewares:- "auth-forward"` goes well, I can even pull and push hello world, but nothing bigger.

I was expecting to be able to pull and push bigger images, I imagine it has something to do with https but is not clear to me.